# Differential ecuation of a parabolic antenna

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's known that the paralel beams that beat in a parabolic antenna are reflected to a point. Moreover, the angle of incidence is the same as the angle of reflection. I'd like to know if someone can give me the differential ecuation of a parabolic antenna

Comment: What about $xy'=2y$ ? By the way, there isn't *one* equation.

Comment: Yes, there isn't one ecuation, but how have you got that one?

Comment: $y=ax^2\to y'=2ax\to xy'=2y$.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but I had to do the exercise without knowing that the function is $\ {a*x^2}$

Comment: Ask your question differently then.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is the wave equation
$$\partial_{ct}^{2}\vec{\Psi}+\Delta\vec{\Psi}=0$$
The solution is
$$\vec{\Psi}(t, \vec{r})=\int\vec{\Psi}_{i}(\omega, \vec{q})e^{i\omega{t}-\vec{q}\cdot{\vec{r}}}d\omega{d}^{3}q+\int\vec{\Psi}_{s}(\omega, \vec{q})e^{i\omega{t}+\vec{q}\cdot{\vec{r}}}d\omega{d}^{3}q$$
Where the indicies $i, s$ stand for the incident wave and scattered wave respectively. Assume that your paraboloid is given by $\Sigma=\{z=ax^{2}+ay^{2}\}$. Then you take the solution $\Psi$ and apply the boundary conditions at $\Sigma$. Assuming that the paraboloid is a perfect reflector, you would get something like
$$\vec{\Psi}|_{\vec{r}\in\Sigma}=0$$
$$\nabla\wedge\vec{\Psi}|_{\vec{r}\in\Sigma}=0$$
Which will give you the relation between incident and scattered signals. The intensity maxima of the scattered signal will lie at some point on the $z$ axis (no surprize))) the location of this point will be dependent on $a$ (i guess), so you want to adjust $a$ depending on the position of your receiver.

Comment: It can be correct, but we don't have such a high level of physic, so we have to do the exercise as in the previous answer